# How to remove the weird line on the right side of the gutter in InteilliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I remove this light green color on the side of the gutter in IntelliJ?  It's right next to the tear line.  It's really distracting me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green background color in the gutter are indicators for version control. Green means those lines have been added. You can disable VCS all together (and manage it from command line for example). But you can also tweak or disable the appearance. Here is how:

Go to `settings / preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> VCS` and open the editor gutter settings. Open each individual sub-item and untick the checkbox next to background.

[image: settings screenshot]